# Bigcartel Collection Order

Tags: collections, bigcartel

I'm using the NEAT theme in #bigcartel - and by default the COLLECTIONS page alphabetises A-Z.

I was wondering what needs to be changed in the PRODUCTS CSS page to change this? Whether it's Z-A, or maybe even by popularity (if possible) ?

Cheers

Comment: Need help then contact me https://www.fiverr.com/wetechteam/design-and-develop-eye-catchy-big-cartel-store-to-boost-sell

Answer (score 1):

The "Collections" page just pulls category names in the order they're sorted in your admin. To change that, visit the Products page in your admin and click on any product to edit it. Then under the "Category" subheading, click Edit categories and drag them in your preferred sorting order.